# Android Font Change

Tags: android, eclipse, fonts

I am trying to create an android app that will change the font at the push of a button. I have searched through stackoverflow and other sites on Google, but have come up empty handed. I am using Eclipse. The goal is to be able to simply touch a button that reads "times new roman" and then have the text above change to that font. I found people trying to change the font in Eclipse, or simply the default font for their app, but not have the user be able to change it. I got this idea after finding an app that changes background colors. Does anyone know what code I need for the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeface is what you are looking for.

In the *onclicklistener* of the button, try something like

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(...);
Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(...);
txt.setTypeface(tf);
```